# Ruby one line ifelse statement not working with Sinatra commands?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

When I use a shortened `if/else` statement with Sinatra commands, I receive a syntax error:

```
request.cookies['blog'].nil? ? erb :blog : redirect '/done'
```

Returns this error:

```
/home/sinatra/ptt/ptt.rb:107: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' request.cookies['blog'].nil? ? "erb :blog" : redirect '/done' ^
```

Both of the statements produce errors when by themselves (without Sinatra code as the other statement).

Is this a Sinatra problem or is the syntax incorrect?

The error does not occur when the true/false statements are plain Ruby:

```
request.cookies['blog'].nil? ? foo = 1 : bar = 2
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Ruby can't decide what is a method call and what belongs to the `if` statement. Try this:

```
request.cookies['blog'].nil? ? erb(:blog) : redirect('/done')
```